# Mapping a url path to a server in nginx

Tags: nginx

How can I map a URI of the form `staging.example.com/siteA` to a virtual server located at `/var/www/siteA`?

The main restriction is that I do not want to create a subdomain for siteA. All examples of nginx.conf I've seen so far rely on having a subdomain to do the mapping.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may use the [root directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root) within a `location` block, like this:

```
server {
    server_name staging.example.com;
    root /some/other/location;
    location /siteA/ {
        root /var/www/;
    }
}
```

Then `http://staging.example.com/foo.txt` points to `/some/other/location/foo.txt`, while `http://staging.example.com/siteA/foo.txt` points to `/var/www/siteA/foo.txt`.

Note that the `siteA` directory is still expected to exist on the filesystem. If you want `http://staging.example.com/siteA/foo.txt` to point to `/var/www/foo.txt`, you must use the [`alias` directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias):

```
location /siteA/ {
    alias /var/www;
}
```