# How to change the access url of official phpmyadmin docker image to http://localhost/phpmyadmin?

Tags: nginx, docker, phpmyadmin

I downloaded official phpmyadmin docker image (https://store.docker.com/community/images/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin). Everything is OK.

Just one problem for me: the access url is `http://localhost` and I wan it to become `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`.

I did some research and found the key is in `/etc/nginx.conf` which is called by supervisord. Here's the snippet in `/etc/nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    root /www;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    charset utf-8;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
       return 405;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;

        # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

        # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
        # see: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_buffering off;

        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

        # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
        fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny  all;
    }

    location ~ /(libraries|templates) {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to modify this `nginx.conf` to make the access url become `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`?

Answer (score 4):

I would not recommend to solve this issue in Nginx. It could be error prone, especially if someone does reverse proxy.

---

It seems official phpmyadmin image is based on Apache.

Unfortunately, as of 2021 phpmyadmin cannot be served from /phpmyadmin

So you have to build additional layer by yourself:

```
FROM phpmyadmin

RUN mv /var/www/html /var/www/phpmyadmin
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
RUN mv /var/www/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

Or you can use image which does same for you:

```
laimison/phpmyadmin:latest
```

---

Off topic: if someone asks what configuration is sufficient in reverse proxy:

```
    location /phpmyadmin {
      proxy_pass http://pma:80;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      break;
    }
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm. Made my day!

Comment: Glad that it was helpful. This type of issue better to solve where web assets/app is served, not in nginx as usual.

Comment: Just tested symlink successfully:

`FROM phpmyadmin

RUN ln -s /var/www/html /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 1):

You could try and simply change `location / {` with an [`alias` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias):

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
  alias /www;
  ...
```

That would serve the same root files, but only for the url `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

Regarding docker, it means you need to docker build your own image, with a Dockerfile starting with `FROM phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.6`, and COPYing a modified version of `nginx.conf`, a bit like this [`3bdigital/docker-phpmyadmin`](https://github.com/3bdigital/docker-phpmyadmin) repo.

---

The [OP faraday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7482755/faraday) chose the simpler approach of:

> build(ing) a docker image myself with ubuntu as base image and phpmyadmin installed.
>   It works under `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` after installation.

Comment: Doesn't work. The access url is stilll http://localhost.  And I also gave some other try, modify location into other formats, but with no luck.  I'm quite new to nginx......

Comment: @faraday I forgot to add alias. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/19675956/6309

Comment: Still not working. With alias, when I visit  localhost/phpmyadmin, I got "403 forbidden".

Comment: @faraday Strange: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21401899/6309 shows it should work, but maybe you simply have a chmod / chown access right issue (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20182383/6309). See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/35278268/6309

Comment: After struggling with this problem, I decided to give up. I build a docker image myself with ubuntu as base image and phpmyadmin installed. It works under ttp://localhost/phpmyadmin after installation.  Still really thanks for your help.

Comment: @faraday Sorry to hear that. I'll keep looking if I see any other causes for this issue.

Comment: @faraday I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.